# Use saved input for scripts

Tags: shell-script, buffer

I have a few scripts that I constantly enter in input as below:

```
[support@ccfcore-3 exporttool]$ ./sendExamToRepo.sh
Enter the Study Instance UID:
2.25.98472613238667427310842065102689842379
```

The script itself uses a basic echo and read statement:

```
echo "Enter the Study Instance UID: "
read SUID
```

Is there a way I can save the input I enter into a sort of text file or into a buffer so that when I need to re-enter it, I don't have to constantly go through log files to copy the input again (I get the input from log files)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe it to stdin of the script:

```
echo 2.25.9847261 | ./sendExamToRepo.sh
```

Or redirect stdin to come from a file:

```
./sendExamToRepo.sh < SUID.txt
```

Comment: Perfect, the echo statement works good enough for me!! thanks